# How can I set web-mode to use comment-dwim?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

I want `web-mode` to use `comment-dwim` instead of `web-mode-comment-or-uncomment` (bound to `M-;`).

I tried:

```el
;; Web Mode (http://web-mode.org/)
(with-eval-after-load 'web-mode
  (setq
   web-mode-markup-indent-offset 2
   web-mode-css-indent-offset 2
   web-mode-code-indent-offset 2)
  ;; (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html?\\'" . web-mode))
  (global-set-key (kbd "M-;") 'comment-dwim))
```

But the change doesn't apply, I've also tried with `local-set-key`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(with-eval-after-load 'web-mode
  (define-key web-mode-map (kbd "M-;") 'comment-dwim))
```

Comment: I have an issue with that. Now I can successfully comment the way it should, but when I try to uncomment it re-comments instead (so 2 comments delimiters around my region).

Comment: I guess that's why web-mode comes with its own commenting command.